# SASS iteration with different animation distance for each iteration

Tags: sass, iteration

I am trying to figure out the correct formula to make each iteration translate to a different location.

Let's say I have 5 and they all start off next to each other. I now want to translate them across the screen, using @keyframes, but I want them to stop and different locations by the end of the animation. So essentially whether its the X, Y, or Z plane I want the first iteration to stop at 50px, the second at 70px, third at 100px, and so on. How can this be achieved?

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

```
.block {
  position:absolute;
  left:10%;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  animation:animate 2s linear forwards;
  
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    $delay: calc(.3s * (#{$i}));
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      top: calc(20px * (#{$i}));
      animation-delay:$delay;
  }
    @keyframes animate {
      0%{transform:translate3d(0,0,0);}
      100%{transform:translate3d(calc(20px * (#{$i})),0,0);}
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried many variations to the formula listed in the @keyframes but no luck they always end back next to each other. Here is a codepen to play with. https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/eYZewXd?editors=1100

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this? [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/gOroPzY).

**Sass**:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      animation: animation#{$i} #{2s - (.2s * ($i - 1))} #{.2s * ($i - 1)} linear forwards;
      
      @keyframes animation#{$i} {
        0% {
          transform: translateX(0);
        }
        100% {
          transform: translateX(#{200px - (20px * ($i - 1))});
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation: animation1 2s 0s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes animation1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation: animation2 1.8s 0.2s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes animation2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(180px);
  }
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation: animation3 1.6s 0.4s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes animation3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(160px);
  }
}
div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation: animation4 1.4s 0.6s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes animation4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(140px);
  }
}
div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation: animation5 1.2s 0.8s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes animation5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(120px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: yes yes yes I think I can manipulate this into what I really need. I am not 100% sure though what these two formulas do. #{2s - (.2s * ($i - 1))} and #{.2s * ($i - 1)} Is the first one the duration and the second the delay? Thank you!

Comment: Exactly. `#{2s - (.2s * ($i - 1))}` is the duration, starting at 2s for the first item ` 2s * (1 - 1)` and then - `.2s` for each following. `#{.2s * ($i - 1)}` is the delay, again starting at `0` for the first and ending with `.2s * (5 - 1)` = `.8s` so that each reaches the destination at the same moment even if starting offset, you could remove that tho.

Comment: @JustinNorthup. I guess this is what you wanted https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/gOroPzY

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!